# Jekyll Github Action stopped working and now fails with error message: "Cannot publish on branch master"

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-actions

I have a blog deployed on Github Pages. I use [Jekyll Github Action](https://github.com/helaili/jekyll-action) and everything worked fine until my last deployment some 3 months ago. I created a new entry and now I get an error: **"Cannot publish on branch master"**.

This is my Workflow:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: helaili/jekyll-action@2.0.1
        env:
          JEKYLL_PAT: ${{ secrets.JEKYLL_PAT }}
          JEKYLL_ENV: production
```

This is the configuration of Github Pages, we haven't changed anything:

[image]

We used to push to `master` so that the action would generate the site on `gh-pages` but it stopped working. I know that the action is now on version 2.1.0 but I would expect my configuration to still be working.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I don't know why it worked before because this is an `org.github.io` type of repo, and looking at the [source code of the action](https://github.com/helaili/jekyll-action/blob/2.0.1/entrypoint.sh#L31) it used this information to decide the branch (`master` or `gh-pages`). Unfortunately the logs of the previous builds are not available to trace the problem.

To make it work I had to upgrade to 2.0.5 and use the `target_branch` input:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: helaili/jekyll-action@2.0.5
        with:
          target_branch: 'gh-pages'
        env:
          JEKYLL_PAT: ${{ secrets.JEKYLL_PAT }}
          JEKYLL_ENV: production
```